# What to call a store that sells end mills?

Tags: hardware

I need to pick up an end mill, today. Mail order isn't an option.

I've been googling for over an hour now, looking for a place in my area that sells end mills. Every search term I've tried leads back to either generic hardware stores or machine shops.

What do you call a store that sells end mills, such that google can find one for you?

Comment: You might want to think about taking a different route to find a store.  Start with the manufacture web site, see if they have a list of reps or stores that sells their products.  If they don't, they should have a sales rep you can contact that can get the information on where you can purchase.

Comment: You don't say where you're located, but assuming you're in the USA, half the day (or more) is gone already, but if you order now, Amazon  has a selection of end mills they can deliver tomorrow. So if it's really urgent, you might want to order what you need while you continue to search for a local source. You could always ask the guy at the local machine shop where they buy theirs, if you're really desperate they might even be willing to sell you what you need.

Comment: Welding supply shop? Honestly, getting obscure specialty parts is exactly what the internet is great for. I would call McMaster-Carr and see if they can overnight a part this late in the day.

Comment: A Machine shop might be what you want.  They don't normally sell tools, but if you need one _right now_ they might be willing to make you a deal.

Comment: The path to finding an end mill ended up being: Go to a wood store that has a small selection of mills. Spend money there; enough that they're already comfortable that you're they're customer, and don't mind introducing you to a store with more tools. Find out their favorite place to shop for endmills. And that store didn't have a category other than "woodworking shop".

Comment: See the [meta discussion](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/607/2196) for more details about our product recommendation policy.

Comment: This is not a product request question. This is a terminology question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Machining and Machine tool supply

Tool and Die Maker's Supplies

Wood Machinery Tool Supply